# "ZeroDivisionError: division by zero"

Tags: python, class, python-3.6

I am a beginner working with Python3.6 and I have no idea why my code will not work properly. Your feedback/help is greatly appreciated.

My instructions for the DriveTo function are as follows:

Now, add a Car method driveTo. It should take two additional parameters, namely, the x and y coordinates of a location for the car to attempt to move. If the car has enough gas to make the trip, the car should be moved, the amount of gas remaining should be updated, and the method should return True. If the car does not have enough gas, it should not be moved or changed at all, and the method should return False

Here is my current code:

```
import math 

class Car:
    def __init__( self , mpg , fuel , money ):
        self.mpg = mpg
        self.fuel = fuel
        self.money = money

    #return current location of car in two element list
    def getLocation( self ):
        return [ self.x , self.y ]

    #returns the number of gallons left in the car 
    def getGas( self ):
        self.fuel -= 1
        return self.fuel

    #returns how much gas the car needs to be at capacity 
    def getToFill( self ):
        current_tank =  self.getGas() 
        gas_needed = ( self.fuel - current_tank )
        return gas_needed

    #return true or false if enough gas
    def driveTo( self , x , y ):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        miles_pg = (self.mpg / self.getToFill())
        miles = math.sqrt( ( self.x - x )**2 + ( self.y - y )**2 )



        if miles >= miles_pg:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Comment: Could you add how you test the code

Comment: Could you specifiy which line is giving the error?

Comment: Put the whole stack trace in the question. It shows you (and us) exactly where your error is occurring, then those values can be traced backwards to see where it went wrong.

Comment: If the `self.fuel` is equal to `current_tank`...

Comment: I am testing the code using Mac's Terminal and the error is specifically with line 29                                                                                                            "File "car.py", line 29, in driveTo
    miles_pg = (self.mpg / self.getToFill())"

Answer (score 2):

Your subject says that you are getting a division by zero error. I only see one divide operation in your code (though there could be other indirect ones):

```
miles_pg = (self.mpg / self.getToFill())
```

If `self.getToFill()` returns 0, you will get the ZeroDivisionError. What exactly should happen when there is no gas to fill, I don't know. But you need to deal with it.

Answer (score 1):

In `getToFill()` you return `gas-needed`, which is equal to `self.fuel - current_tank`. `current_tank` get's defined in `getGas()`, which returns `self.fuel`, thus `gas_needed` = 0.

So `miles_pg = (self.mpg / self.getToFill())` returns the error, as `getToFill()` returns 0.

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide the output log with the error messages. It looks like at some point your `getToFill()` method is returning zero. A quick solution would be to check that it doesn't return zero before you do `miles_pg = (self.mpg / self.getToFill())`.

Comment: I'd love to provide that for you, but I am not sure how.

Comment: First try checking if the value that ```getToFill()``` returns is zero. If it is zero, do something else, that is, throw an exception or return.

Answer (score 1):

Well there's only one line of code where you are performing a division operation, in driveTo():

```
miles_pg = (self.mpg / self.getToFill())
```

If you want this to never throw an error, you'll either need to catch and handle that possible exception, or ensure that the getToFill() function never returns a value of 0.

Just as a general comment, I don't really know what the functionality or requirements for this class are but most these functions don't really make logical sense from my perspective. Like why does the getGas() function subtract a gallon from the fuel value? What is that function trying to simulate? Looking at the comment above the function I would think that it should just return the value of fuel and nothing else.

Furthermore, what are you doing to calculate the remaining fuel mileage in driveTo()? That doesn't make any mathematical sense to me. If I have the MPG and the total gallons of fuel for a car, I would calculate the remaining fuel mileage like this:

```
miles_left_until_out_of_fuel = self.mpg * self.fuel
```

Think about it, if I have 2 gallons left in my tank and I know my car gets 20 MPG, then I'm going to have 2 * 20 = 40 miles until I run out of fuel.

Answer (score 0):

You don't check if there's any gas left.

Thus if `getToFill()` returns 0 then `self.mpg / gas` results in `ZeroDivisionError: division by zero`.

```
def driveTo( self , x , y ):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    gas = self.getToFill()
    if gas <= 0:
        # No more gas
        return False
    miles_pg = (self.mpg / gas)
    miles = math.sqrt( ( self.x - x )**2 + ( self.y - y )**2 )
```

Comment: I tried this, but it still says "ZeroDivisionError: division by zero."

Comment: @mafertes Well that isn't possible. I also tested this before posting, verifying that it worked.

Comment: You're right! It works, but unfortunately it's still not correct. Apparently the test did not pass and somewhere during testing my car was .001 or more miles out of the expected location.